Do I need cake dowels for a two tier cake (two layers in each tier)
I want to bake a two tiered cake. I have two 9 inch pans and two 6 inch pans. I'm not sure if you can just adapt any recipe for this as it adjust two layers in each tier?
Do I need cake dowels?

related https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/39746/67

You may not need dowels for a two tier cake, but it really depends on the cake itself.
A pound cake or other cake intended for stacking tends to be denser and better able to support the weight of an upper tier, Especially if the upper tier is a less dense cake.
Trying to stack on top of a chiffon cake or similar airy cake is going to require additional support
